# Saving the content of an array into a variable

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array in a function (`get_travel_reports_places()`) called `$places` in which several locations are saved in (e.g. "Bangkok, Thailand", "Vientiane, Laos", ...).

I now want to put the content of this array into a variable which I can return. The goal is to call the function like this

```
<?php echo get_travel_reports_places(); ?>
```

and get a list of the places, seperated with a `|`:

```
Bangkok, Thailand|Vientiane Laos
```

I tried to do it with a `foreach` loop, but this only works when I `echo` the places directly. Storing them in a single variable doesn't work.

Anyone willing to help me out?

Comment: Do you want to add the code for `get_travel_reports_places()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using [join(), which is an alias of implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
join("|", $places);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the implode function.

`return implode('|', $places);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$places = get_travel_reports_places();
echo implode('|', $places);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

To correct your question, you want to return a string, not an array.

The code would be as follows:

```
function get_travel_report_places() {
  // your regular code here
  return implode(' | ', $places);
}
```

This function will join all the places in the `$places` array and return a string with the places separated by `|`.

Comment: Thank you, easier than I thought :)